# Tracking build number along with version in a program

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins

I'm trying to get the below setup running in my system

1. A node.js app
2. Jenkins pipeline

My company would like to start tracking version changes in the nodejs app in the below format

`x.x.x.BUILD_NUMBER` or `x.x.x+BUILD_NUMBER`

I understand that generating the first three bits can be handled by node.js by running something as simple as `npm release patch` or something but how do i start tracking the build number? The build number is only generated once the commit is done and the app runs in jenkins.

I am considering two ways to do this - both of which seem to have their own drawbacks. Was wondering if there are better ways to handle this.

1. In my `package.json` file - also keep track of the build number like the below

   {
     "version": "0.7.10",
     "build": "1"
   }

   On every `git commit` - add a post-commit hook to uptick the build number. In this case, there isn't any version tracking done by Jenkins. Is there a chance that the incrementing build number generated by jenkins could diverge from the node.js tracked build no?
2. Once a build is run and generated by Jenkins - run a script on post success/failure to include the build number in the `package.json` file. Commit and push to git repo - this would mean theres an un-necessary additional commit on the repo.

Aside from the above , is there a simpler way to start tracking build numbers in such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

i think there isn't an optimal solution to do exactly what you're asking. instead of putting the build number in source control, maybe you could either 1) keep jenkins builds forever, since there's a record of the build number there, and you could log the app's x.x.x version as well, or 2) you could include the build number in a build-generated artifact (if you push to artifactory or nexus or a docker registry or something).

if you must have the build number in source control, you probably want to do a post-build commit, but, like you say, this will result in an extra commit for each build, and, by default, these commits will in turn cause builds. And then you'll want to suppress the builds for these commits, so that's another problem to solve with this approach.